# insert datarow value at particular row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarow

I want to insert datarow value in datatable particular row. Am having a datatable with values and then i want to overwrite the particular row value using c#.

my partial code id here:

```
   for (int j = 0; j < DT.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                row = DT2.NewRow();

                row["Employee ID"] = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[j]["fldempid"]);
                row["Employee Name"] = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[j]["fldempname"]);
                string leavehstry = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[j]["fldleavehistory"]);
                string[] textarray1 = leavehstry.Split('-');
                char[] delimiterChars1 = { ':' };
                for (int i = 1; i <= textarray1.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string[] words = textarray1[i - 1].Split(delimiterChars1);
                    string value = words[0].ToString();
                    string value1 = words[1].ToString();
                    row[value] = value1;
                    ivalue = i;

                }
                //DT2.Rows[j].Delete(); //I want to insert (or) overwrite the row value at j th position. 
                //DT2.Rows.Add(row);
                //DT2.Rows[j].AcceptChanges();


            }
```

please help me to insert it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a DataRow in a DataTable at a specified index location by using the [`InsertAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat.aspx) method.

You might do this in place of your three commented out lines:

```
DT2.InsertAt(row, j);
```

Answer (score 0):

If EmployerID  is an unique value,  then compare the DataColumn "EmployerID" value with EmployerID and Assign the datarow values as you want by using for loop.